# How to use Google Map API for Web?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I am new For Google Map API so i don't know how to use it.

So i want some guidance or reference link to work on it.

Need :

I have a location on map and i want to show some custom markers such as For schools, hospitals etc.

i have tabs for Schools, Hospitals etc.

when i click on schools then in 2km(dropdown for KM) show all schools around my location and when hover or click on particular school it automatically tells us how much distance from my location.

Image Like this :

[image]

I have read google map reference link :

https://developers.google.com/maps/web/

But i am very confused. So please give some advise and useful link.

Another Image :

[image]

Comment: You have the only link you need found by yourself. Just read further,watch the code examples. What you try to do, is easy and most of it provided by google itself with code examples. In general SO is not about helping getting started!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created a working example for you. To get your current location press `Get My Location` and it would use HTML5 geolocation API to get your coordinates and `google.maps.Geocoder` to translate those coordinates into an address. Press `Show Locations In Radius` to show radius on map and also show only markers which are within the radius. This function uses various google maps API calls to draw radius (`google.maps.Circle`), markers (`google.maps.Marker` - read API if you want to know more about custom styling), `Geocoder` and also `google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween` which computes distance between two locations in meters. The example works with dummy location data `all_locations` (those are just example markers around New York's Second Street) which you would replace with your data. When you click on a marker, it would display distance in meters from the input location. To see the example location, input "Second Steet, New York" as address. (Get My Location won't work inside the snippet iframe, you have to try it on your localhost)

```js
var map = null;
  var radius_circle = null;
  var markers_on_map = [];
  var geocoder = null;
  var infowindow = null;
  
  //all_locations is just a sample, you will probably load those from database
  var all_locations = [
   {type: "restaurant", name: "Restaurant 1", lat: 40.723080, lng: -73.984340},
   {type: "school", name: "School 1", lat: 40.724705, lng: -73.986611},
   {type: "school", name: "School 2", lat: 40.724165, lng: -73.983883},
   {type: "restaurant", name: "Restaurant 2", lat: 40.721819, lng: -73.991358},
   {type: "school", name: "School 3", lat: 40.732056, lng: -73.998683}
  ];

  //initialize map on document ready
  $(document).ready(function(){
      var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(40.723080, -73.984340); //you can use any location as center on map startup
      var myOptions = {
        zoom: 1,
        center: latlng,
        mapTypeControl: true,
        mapTypeControlOptions: {style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU},
        navigationControl: true,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
      };
      map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
   geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
      google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(){
           if(infowindow){
             infowindow.setMap(null);
             infowindow = null;
           }
      });
      $('#location_type').change(function(){
         if(radius_circle) showCloseLocations();
      });
  });
  
  function showCloseLocations() {
   var i;
   var radius_km = $('#radius_km').val();
   var address = $('#address').val();
    var location_type = $('#location_type').val();

   //remove all radii and markers from map before displaying new ones
   if (radius_circle) {
    radius_circle.setMap(null);
    radius_circle = null;
   }
   for (i = 0; i < markers_on_map.length; i++) {
    if (markers_on_map[i]) {
     markers_on_map[i].setMap(null);
     markers_on_map[i] = null;
    }
   }

   if (geocoder) {
    geocoder.geocode({'address': address}, function (results, status) {
     if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
      if (status != google.maps.GeocoderStatus.ZERO_RESULTS) {
       var address_lat_lng = results[0].geometry.location;
       radius_circle = new google.maps.Circle({
        center: address_lat_lng,
        radius: radius_km * 1000,
        clickable: false,
      map: map
       });
                    if (radius_circle) map.fitBounds(radius_circle.getBounds());
       for (var j = 0; j < all_locations.length; j++) {
        (function (location) {
         var marker_lat_lng = new google.maps.LatLng(location.lat, location.lng);
         var distance_from_location = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(address_lat_lng, marker_lat_lng); //distance in meters between your location and the marker
         if (location_type == location.type && distance_from_location <= radius_km * 1000) {
          var new_marker = new google.maps.Marker({
           position: marker_lat_lng,
           map: map,
           title: location.name
          });              google.maps.event.addListener(new_marker, 'click', function () {
                                    if(infowindow){
             infowindow.setMap(null);
             infowindow = null;
           }
           infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(
            { content: '<div style="color:red">'+location.name +'</div>' + " is " + distance_from_location + " meters from my location",
              size: new google.maps.Size(150,50),
              pixelOffset: new google.maps.Size(0, -30)
            , position: marker_lat_lng, map: map});
          });
          markers_on_map.push(new_marker);
         }
        })(all_locations[j]);
       }
      } else {
       alert("No results found while geocoding!");
      }
     } else {
      alert("Geocode was not successful: " + status);
     }
    });
   }
  }
  
  function getMyAdress() {
   if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
     geocoder.geocode({latLng: new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude)}, function (results, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
       if (results[0]) {
        $('#address').val(results[0].formatted_address);
       } else {
        alert("No results found");
       }
      } else {
       alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
      }
     });
    }, function () {
     alert("Unable to find my location!");
    });
   }
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
        google.load("maps", "3",{other_params:"sensor=false&libraries=geometry"});
      </script>

<body style="margin:0px; padding:0px;" >
 <input id="address" value="Second Steet, New York" placeholder="Input Address"/>
 <select id="radius_km">
  <option value=1>1km</option>
  <option value=2>2km</option>
  <option value=5>5km</option>
  <option value=30>30km</option>
 </select>
 <select id="location_type">
  <option value="restaurant">Restaurant</option>
  <option value="school">School</option>
 </select>
 <button onClick="getMyAdress()">Get My Location</button>
 <button onClick="showCloseLocations()">Show Locations In Radius</button>
 <div id="map_canvas"  style="width:500px; height:300px;">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks mate to given me your precious time, when i click your custom marker such as 'Restaurant' it gives an alert prompt. how can i show a label on clicked marker where i will show details of clicked marker instead of alert.

Comment: I added a new image, can you please see it give an idea. Because you understand what i want.

Comment: I have edited the answer. It now uses new google.maps.InfoWindow to display a window over the marker when clicked. You can custom the content inside the infowindow using HTML and CSS (check line: infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow( { content: .. in code)

Comment: Again Thank you so much, can you send me some google map links to modify it according to me. I want to add some buttons like Restaurants, Hospitals etc. if i click on Hospitals then all hospitals show around my location in circle area.

Comment: You don't need any additional maps API functionality to achieve that. I have modified the example to have location type dropdown. just make sure all your locations have location_type set (see all_locations array in my example) and then when displaying markers on map (code around var new_marker = new google.maps.Marker...) check if selected location_type == location.type. You can upvote the answer if you like it.

Comment: To customize markers so they have different icons check this: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorials/custom-markers#customize_marker_icons_for_different_markers