# Google Map API for addesses search

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have been searching for some information on what I want to achieve but not getting any clear answers.

I have a database with thousands of addresses. I want that when the user searches by entering a postcode, the search should show all the available addresses close to the postcode in a map. Zooming In would obviously show closer address to the search postcode (and hence less search results) and zooming out would also include farther addresses (and hence more search results). And then clicking the location icon would display the complete address.

Do I need to store the addresses as longitude and latitude or google map can search a location using postcode? If I need to store the longitude and latitude then whats the best way to convert an address to long and lat?

I really appreciate if you can point me to any useful links or reusable code.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand it, you want to find all closest locations from YOUR data to some location, which is identified by a postcode.

First, you have to convert all your addresses to coordinates (Latitude and Longitude). You can do that using Google Geocode API, you will have to create as script, which calls Google Geocode API for every single address in your db:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=EXAMPLE_ADDRES&key=YOUR_API_KEY
```

The response this script brings you is documented [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro#ErrorMessages). You can parse it to get latitude and longitude for each locations and store them in your database. BEWARE of limitations of the Google Geocode API. They are listed [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/usage-limits#increase-your-quota-by-enabling-pay-as-you-go-billing). You have to create your script in a way that won't exceed those limits. Also read [this article](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/geocodestrat#caching) for caching the results of geocoding, to make sure you don't violate the terms of service. The article also contains some best practices and examples of server side geocoding.

Now, when somebody inputs postcode to your application, you can use the geocoding API or [Google maps Geocoding service](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding) to translate postcode to coordinate and using haversine formula you can calculate the closest locations from your db, to coordinates of the postcode location. You can do that on frontend side, example in this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37088202/2661226) (instead of address you will input postcode + state/country in the address bar) or on backend side, if you use MySQL check this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36882407/how-to-select-longitude-latitude-around-specifc-location-from-mysql/36888935#36888935).